# CSS fixed element appear over scrollbars

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have seen a few questions about somewhat the same issue, but none of the specified answers actually work for this one.

Consider the following snippet :

```js
$(function () {
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    /**
      THIS SHOULD NOT BE CALLED!!!
      So, change some colors to warn about it, if it happens.
    */
    $('#content').css('background-color', 'red');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
    
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
    
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999999;
    
  overflow: auto;
}

#nav {
  background-color:rgb(50,50,50);
  color: white;

  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#content-wrapper {
  background-color:rgb(200,200,200);

  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:2;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 240);
  
  position: fixed; 
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="nav">
    Navbar
  </div>
    
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <div>
        Begin
      </div>
      <div style="height: 600px;">
        ...
      </div>
      <div>
        End
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div id="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

The scrollbar goes underneath `nav` and `footer`. Since this is **very** important that *only* the `container` element scrolls (the `BODY` element must **not** scroll), how can I fix this? Is it possible?

The HTML structure should essentially be as suggested in this question (fixed nav, full height content, etc.). I have tried several tricks; modifying `z-index`es, wrapping things around, etc., I'm at a lost here.

The targeted browser is Google Chrome, as this is the adopted browser in use for this application. The ideal solution would make the fixed element adjust their width to compensate for the `overflow: auto;` on the `container` element.

Comment: Does the #container element need to be scrolled at all? Could you instead just scroll #content since it looks like you always want the nav and footer in fixed positions?

Comment: @TheLeggett Yes, that could be a viable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Demo in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dddmx3u/)

An alternative approach here would be to only scroll the #content-wrapper from your example. Here's a basic example of how this might be done:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav">
        Navbar
    </div>

    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div>
                Begin
            </div>
            <div style="height: 600px;">
                ...
            </div>
            <div>
                End
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav {
    background-color:rgb(50,50,50);
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#content-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    bottom:40px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:rgb(200,200,200);
    width: 100%;
    overflow:scroll;

}

#footer {
    background-color: rgb(220, 220, 240);
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Of course! The actual implementation is a little more complicated, and I need to adapt it (using Bootstrap, and some other CSS that needs to be cleaned up)

Answer (score 4):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/0xvmdrxq/)

Remove `overflow:auto` from `#container`.

So the **CSS** for `#container` would be like

```
#container {
  position: absolute;    
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Add `overflow:auto` to `#content`.

Comment: In your fiddle, if you scroll, the content becomes red; meaning that this solution does not work.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but please try to test your answer before posting. The content still turns red as a result of the window scroll event.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to achieve with that script..that scroll event will be triggered when you start scrolling in the window..

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/a8xqhh3L/

Remove `overflow: auto` from `#container`.

Comment: Sorry, if it was that simple, I wouldn't have asked in the first place. Look at the JS part of the fiddle and the behaviour when you scroll the HTML viewport.